# Expectation (x/y) using jacobian

Tags: self-study, expected-value, density-function, jacobian

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be two independent random variables with the density
> functions:
>
> - $f(x) = 3 x^2$, for $0<x<1$, $0$ elsewhere
> - $g(y) = 4y^3$, for $0 <y<1$, $0$ elsewhere     Give $\mathbb E(x/y)$

I tried this using a Jacobian transformation.  Took $x/y = z$, and $y= w$
Solved the jacobian matrix and arrived at the joint distribution as $12z^2w^6$.
The limits are however coming as $0<w<1$ and $0<z<w$.  How do I then proceed with the expectation? The upper limit for $z$ stands at $w$.

Comment: Hint: You do need a Jacobian since $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Comment: Hint: You don't need Jacobians and stuff. $$E\left[\frac XY\right] = \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac xy f(x)g(y) \mathrm dx\mathrm dy.$$

Comment: I got this; wanted to see if jacobian works